# What are the possible ways to create a two-way binding between properties using Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript

Say, I have an object type that implements a 3D-object, which has both quaternion and 3-axis rotation properties:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, 'rotation', {
    ...
});

Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, 'quaternion', {
    ...
});
```

and I want to make sure that each time I modify each of them, another property is recalculated automatically. Obviously, if I make both set methods of those properties, I'll run into infinite loop.

So far, the only way of doing this that I can see is to actually use another set of properties that resemble rotation and quaternion (probably non-enumerable, for a bit cleaner object introspection):

```
Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, '_rotation', {
    enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, '_quaternion', {
    enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, 'rotation', {
    get: function() {
        return this._rotation;
    },
    set: function(r) {
        this._rotation = r;
        this._quaternion = rotation2quaternion(r);
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(MyObject3D.prototype, 'quaternion', {
    get: function() {
        return this._rotation;
    },
    set: function(q) {
        this._quaternion = q;
        this._rotation= quaternion2rotation(q);
    }
});
```

Any better ways you can come up with? Maybe I'm missing some abilities of Object.defineProperty that could make this even cleaner and shorter?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making `rotation` and `quaternion` accessor properties wouldn't it be simpler to make them data properties and then define a `setRotation` and a `setQuaternion` method to mutate them? For example:

```
function MyObject3D() {
    ...
}

MyObject3D.prototype.setRotation = function (r) {
    this.quaternion = rotation2quaternion(r);
    this.rotation = r
    return this;
};

MyObject3D.prototype.setQuaternion = function (q) {
    this.rotation = quaternion2rotation(q);
    this.quaternion = q;
    return this;
};
```

Now you can access `.rotation` and `.quaternion` normally. However to set them you use `.setRotation` and `.setQuaternion` instead. Yes it is unsafe since the user may manually set `.rotation` and `.quaternion`. However it has several advantages:

1. It will work in browsers which don't support `defineProperty`.
2. It allows you to chain operations since it returns `this`.
3. It's easy to understand what the functions do.

---

Another way to solve this problem would be to use immutable objects. This is the way you would do it in Haskell. For example:

```
function MyObject3D(rotation, quaternion) {
    this.quaternion = quaternion;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    Object.freeze(this);
}

MyObject3D.prototype.putRotation = function (r) {
    return new MyObject3D(r, rotation2quaternion(r));
};

MyObject3D.prototype.putQuaternion = function (q) {
    return new MyObject3D(quaternion2rotation(q), q);
};
```

If you have some initialization logic in your constructor then you can move it into a smart constructor:

```
function createMyObject3D(r, q) {
    // some initialization logic
    return new MyObject3D(r, q);
}
```

Hence when you want to create a new object you use `createMyObject3D` and when you want to mutate the object you use `new MyObject3D` passing in the new values. The advantage of the following method is:

1. Your code becomes referentially transparent. Thus it can be subjected to equational reasoning.
2. It still allows you to chain operations since it returns a brand new object.
3. Nobody can tamper with the properties of your object.
4. It's easy to understand what the functions do.

The only disadvantage is that it depends upon `Object.freeze` which may not be present in old browsers. Nevertheless freezing the object is an optional step and can be omitted.

Comment: You have a point here, though I really dislike using setter methods explicitly all the time (just a taste matter, no practical criticism).
In my opinion, the main advantage of your approach is actually different though. Since defineProperty has been introduced very recently, implicit modification of a linked property might be unexpected for a user. But methods are actually different, programmers would take a look at their source code much more likely (and figure out that we modify more than one property by each method).

Comment: @demeshchuk I couldn't have put it in better words. Anyway, I updated my answer and suggested another alternative. I prefer the new alternative as it's more like Haskell. BTW if you don't already program in Haskell then you should. It's an amazing language and I guarantee that learning it will make you a better programmer.

Comment: The functional approach is definitely nice (I like Haskell, but wish I had more time learning it deeper than small academic projects). In my case it might be an overkill, as vectors would get recalculated very frequently, but I'll give it a shot and compare the performance. Thanks for the answers!